# How to nest functions in 1 cell in excel?

Tags: excel

My table in excel

[image]

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F2),"INPUT CHECK DUE",IF([@[CHECK DUE]]<=TODAY(),"FOR DEPOSIT",([@[CHECK DUE]]-TODAY()&" Day(s) remaining")))
```

and above is my code on status Column. Now I am trying to incorporate a function that would change the status from `FOR DEPOSIT` to `DEPOSITED` whenever the remarks column is filled out. Can anybody help or give idea please. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just nest it inside another `IF`?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F2),"INPUT CHECK DUE",IF([@[CHECK DUE]]<=TODAY(),IF([@[remarks]<>"","DEPOSITED","FOR DEPOSIT"),([@[CHECK DUE]]-TODAY()&" Day(s) remaining")))
```

i.e.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F2),
    "INPUT CHECK DUE",
    IF([@[CHECK DUE]]<=TODAY(),
       IF([@[remarks]<>"",
          "DEPOSITED",
          "FOR DEPOSIT"
         ),
       ([@[CHECK DUE]]-TODAY()&" Day(s) remaining")
      )
   )
```